# Windows Phone Silverlight page navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have two questions here about Windows Phone page navigation:

1. Is there a way to get the instance of the page I am navigating to? That is, if I am on page one and want to navigate to page2 to when button click, can I get the page2 instance after page2 is initialized by `NavigationService.Navigate("page_2_uri")` call in page 1?
2. Is there a way I can know which page I navigate from? For example, I am currently on page3, and I want to do something like: if page 3 is navigated from page 2, I will do this, otherwise I will do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The idea for using the NavigationService to navigate between pages is that you don't need to know any details about your destination.  So in your example, Page 2 isn't initialized until you've left Page 1, and therefore Page 1 is no longer in scope, and won't be able to do anything with Page 2.  If you want to pass information/context to Page 2, id recommend using Query Parameters (see next answer).  If you want to know where the navigation is going, you can override the [OnNavigatedFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28v=vs.95%29) event and look at the Uri property of the [NavigationEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationeventargs%28v=vs.95%29).
2. I would recommend looking at the [NavigationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcontext%28v=vs.95%29) property of the Silverlight Page class.  This property lets you view the QueryString of the navigation request.  Using this approach, you could navigate to page 3 using a uri like "page_3?previous_page=2" and then extract the previous_page from the QueryString of the NavigationContext to see where you came from.

Comment: You're forgetting that the previous page will always be in the back-stack, which is traversable!

Comment: Yes, good point, Claus, that is probably an easier way of identifying the previous page.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is there a way to get the instance of the page I am navigating to?

No.

> 1. Is there a way I can know which page I navigate from?

Yes. Traverse the [NavigationService.BackStack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.backstack%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)